# Remove all: whitespaces, \n, \t, backslashes from .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, regex, innerhtml

After serializing `.innerHTML` of some `div` i have got such code (part of it):

```
<div class=\"qa-main-wrapper\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-main\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<h1>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<a href=\"./feed/activity.rss\" original-title=\"Ostatnia aktywność\" title=\"\"><i class=\"icon-rss qam-title-rss\"></i></a>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tOstatnia aktywność\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</h1>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-widgets-main qa-widgets-main-high\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-widget-main qa-widget-main-high\">\n<div style=\" text-align:center; background-color: white; width:100%; padding-top:6px; margin-bottom:5px;\">\n\t<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n\tgoogle_ad_client = 'pub-4644487134112796';\n\tgoogle_ad_width = 728;\n\tgoogle_ad_height = 90;\n\tgoogle_ad_format = '728x90_as';\n\tgoogle_ad_type = \"text_image\";\n\tgoogle_ad_channel = \"\";\n\t</script>\n\t<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js\"></script>\n</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-part-q-list\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<form method=\"post\" action=\"./activity\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-q-list\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-q-list-item\" id=\"q147574\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-q-item-stats\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-voting qa-voting-net\" id=\"voting_147574\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"qa-vote-buttons qa-vote-buttons-net\">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<input name=\"vote_147574_1_q147574\" onclick=\"return qa_vote_click(this);\" type=\"submit\" value=\"+\" class=\"qa-vote-first-button qa-vote-up-button\" original-title=\"Kliknij, aby oddać głos w górę\" title=\"\"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<input name=\"vote_147574_-1_q147574\" onclick=\"return qa_vote_click(this);\" type=\"submit\" value=\"–\" class=\"qa-vote-second-button qa-vote-down-button\" original-title=\"Kliknij, aby oddać głos w dół\" title=\"\"> \n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</div>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
```

I want to remove all:

- unnecessary **whitespaces**
- **\n**
- **\t**
- **\n\t** pairs and repetitions (similar as the two above)
- backslashes, like (**\**), before double quotes (**"**). So then, instead of **\"** i want to have just **"**

I have tried such **regex**: `[\\][\\n][\\t][\\n\\t]+`

, within this: `var cleared = document.querySelector('.qa-body-wrapper').innerHTML.replace(new RegExp('[\\n][\\t][\\n\\t]+'), '');`

, but it doesn't match every occurrence of characters, which I listed above. Also, I don't know how to match those backslashes (before double quotes) with same regex.

Is my regex any good, or totally wrong for what I want to achieve?

**[edit]**

This question can be closed. I did separate Objects with data about each div (including it's content) and send it by JSON - it's very clean and has less data (only necessary things).

Thank Your for `regex` proposals.

Comment: Any reason you ended up with this mess in your code?

Comment: How do you "serialize" the HTML, it seems like you're doing something really wrong if all the newlines and tabs are part of the string.

Comment: This is what I came up with: https://regex101.com/r/lF6vA3/1

Comment: regex for all white spaces [\s]+/g, thanks

Comment: why `innerHTML`? use `textContent  || innerText` instead -- the whitespace will be collapsed for you...

Comment: @andlrc, @adeneo I need to send, inside JSON, serialized HTML content of some DIV, which is one of main elements of the page. I am using `.innerHTML`, because it gives me all HTML code inside that DIV, so I can reconstruct that DIV on the other side.
@Praveen Kumar, Your regex doesn't remove backslashes.
@WhiteHat, I need HTML content of that DIV, to reconstruct it on the other side of script. `textContent` and `innerText` give me only text of that DIV, not it's HTML code.

Comment: @Chris92 Just use `JSON.parse("\"my text\"")`

Answer (score 1):

A replacement like this might work:

```
str.replace(/\\t|\\n|\\(?=")/g, '');
```

The above will remove literal `\n`, `\t` and `\` before double quotes, eg:

```
'hello\\nworld\\tJohn\\"Doe' -> 'helloworldJohn"Doe'
```

I used a positive lookahead for the `\"`: `\\(?=")`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
new RegExp(/(\\)"|(\\n)|(\\t)|>[^<]*(\s)[^>]*</, 'g')
```

This removes everything you've listed. I've assumed 'unnecessary whitespaces' means whitespace outside html element tags.

Comment: Wouldn't this remove the quote as well as the backslash before it?

Comment: Also no need to `new RegExp(...)` just use `var regex = /.../g`

Comment: @andlrc no, it wouldn't. The quote is outside the capturing group. Also, yes that would be the way I would do it, but apparently not the way OP wants to do it.

Comment: It was a rhetorical question. It would remove the quote.

Comment: @JBux, Thank You, Your regex works, except it doesn't seem to remove those backslashes. Why would You remove also double quotes? They are part of HTML tags attributes.

Comment: One more thing - why this regex removes albo **<** and **>** (**&lt** and **&gt**) characters?